# too much space for a column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap 3. I create a 2 column page.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-sm-2 column menu_side">
            left ...
            </div>
        </div>
         <div id="main" class="col-sm-10 column">
         right....
         </div>
   </div>
```

[image: too much space for the left column]

Like you can see, left portion take to much space. I would like to be able to take only a little bit more then the text size.

I tried to reduce to col-sm1, but the text is splitted on two line.

Is there a technic to fix this?

Comment: Add a column width: style="width:100px" or in a percentage: style="width:15%" to override the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

While working with HTML I have found that if you use CSS you can specify the width and height of `<div>` tags. To do this you would create a section of code ether within the same file or on a separate .css style page.

If you chose to put the code on the same page, you would add the fallowing code between the `<head> </head>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
width: (xxx)px;
//replace the (xxx) with the size of the container you would like to have in pixels (or you can replace the pixel number with a percentage)
}
</style>
```

Alternately you can create a new .css file which would have the following code:

```
@charset "utf-*";
div {
    width: (xxx)px;
// again you would replace the (xxx) with the number of pixels you want the width to be or replace the (xxx)px with the percentage of the page you want the container to take up
}
```

If you chose to use a separate CSS file you would add the following code to between the `<head> </head>` tags on which ever page you would like to modify:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

you would replace "styles.css" with what ever you name you .css file

Hope this helps as I have not worked with bootstrap before